# Link to static page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I'm new to PHP and CodeIgniter, and I'm having trouble setting up the routing of static pages in my CodeIgniter app.

I have the `About Us | Contact Us | Privacy Policy` and many other pages in my footer, which when the user clicks, should go to a url like
`mysite.com\about`
`mysite.com\contact`
`mysite.com\privacy`

You get the gist..

Here's what I've done in the footer div in the views folder

```
<a href="home/staticpages/about">About</a> |
<a href="home/staticpages/contact"> Contact Us</a> | 
<a href="home/staticpages">Privacy</a> | 
<a href="home/staticpages">Terms of Use </a>
```

Here's the function in a controller `Home`

```
public function staticpages($page)
    {

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'application/views/'.$page.'.html'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view($page, $data);

   }
```

The static pages are just pure HTML content, with `<p>` fields and no dynamic or javascript stuff. So I have them saved as .html; contact.html, about.html and so on.
I just want to load those pages' content in a `contentbody` div I have created, between the header and the footer, and that's the only thing that changes in the whole site for whatever the user clicks.

When I goto `http://localhost/myapp/home/staticpages/about`

I get the

**`404 Not Found error`**
 `The requested URL /dissekted/home/staticpages/about was not found on this server.`

And it's the one that the browser throws.

Comment: Did you set the base URL in the config file?

Comment: Yes.
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myapp`

Answer (score 3):

config your base url

```
$config['base_url'] =
```

load the helper

first method

```
   $this->load->helper('url');
```

or second method 
 autoload it by changing application/config/autoload.php

use with

```
$this->config->base_url();
```

first check with echo you are getting base url or not

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```

and use with your static link

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/static_file "  />static link</a>
```

ok
make this inside in controllers function like

```
public function static ()
    { 

    $this->load->view('static.html');
}
```

Comment: please note, that base_url accepts parameter. Your href should look like, <?=base_url('static_page');?>

Comment: try with inside with controllers

Answer (score 0):

Check your base URL in the config file and make sure you have the final `/` on the path:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myapp/'
```

Also, I use the `anchor()` function from the URL Helper to take create my links.

That takes care of forming the links correctly and takes into account the base URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
create privacy.php in view folder and use below code to display it.


$this->load->view('page_name'); no need to use extension like static.php.

function privacy() {`enter code here`
        $data['meta_title'] = 'Privacy Policy';
        $data['title'] = 'Privacy Policy';
        $data['main'] = 'root/privacy';
        $this->load->vars($data);
        $this->load->view($this->template or page_name);
}
```